# Openssl : macOS: Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)

Tags: macos, openssl, ssl-certificate

In **macOS** I want to connect to the server using openssl.

With the command 
openssl s_client -connect ipaddress:port -cert path.crt -key path.key.pem

Shows CONNECTED but throws
**Verify return code:19 ( self signed certificate in certificate chain)**

I guess the error is because of missing CA.

To refer to the path of the **chain certificate** in my case its (chain.cert.pem) which is created by combining Root certificate(ca.cert.pem.crt) and Intermediate certificate(ca.cert.pem.crt).

I tested adding the chain certificate as 
**openssl s_client -connect ipaddress:port -CAfile \path\chain.cert.pem -cert path.crt -key path.key.pem**

Here I get error as invalid arguments.Looks like I am not adding the CAfile correctly

1. How do we refer to the chain certificate  in macOS
2. Assuming that the error thrown is because of the missing CA how to add or refer to the chain certificate

Please provide your suggestions so that I can try out connecting with the server.

Comment: Any pointers would be of great help! Thanks in advance.